# Stanford NLP CoreNLP don't do sentence split for chinese

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

My environment:

- CoreNLP 3.5.1
- stanford-chinese-corenlp-2015-01-30-models
- default property file for chinese :`StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties`

  - `annotators = segment, ssplit`

---

My testing text is `"這是第一個句子。這是第二個句子。"`
I get sentence from

```
val sentences = annotation.get(classOf[SentencesAnnotation])
for (sent <- sentences) {
  count+=1
  println("sentence{$count} = " + sent.get(classOf[TextAnnotation]))
}
```

**It always prints the whole testing text as one sentence , not the expected two here :**

```
sentence1 = 這是第一個句子。這是第二個句子。
```

the expected are:

```
expected sentence1 = 這是第一個句子。
expected sentence2 = 這是第二個句子。
```

---

Even the same result if I add more properties like :

```
ssplit.eolonly = false
ssplit.isOneSentence = false
ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak = always
ssplit.boundaryTokenRegex = [.]|[!?]+|[。]|[！？]+
```

---

The CoreNLP logs are

```
Registering annotator segment with class edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ChineseSegmenterAnnotator
Adding annotator segment
Loading Segmentation Model [edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/ctb.gz]...Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/ctb.gz ... Loading Chinese dictionaries from 1 files:
  edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/dict-chris6.ser.gz

loading dictionaries from edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/dict-chris6.ser.gz...Done. Unique words in ChineseDictionary is: 423200
done [56.9 sec].
done. Time elapsed: 57041 ms
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding Segmentation annotation...output: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
INFO: TagAffixDetector: useChPos=false | useCTBChar2=true | usePKChar2=false
INFO: TagAffixDetector: building TagAffixDetector from edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/dict/character_list and edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/dict/in.ctb
Loading character dictionary file from edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/dict/character_list
Loading affix dictionary from edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/dict/in.ctb
這是第一個句子。這是第二個句子。
--->
[這是, 第一, 個, 句子, 。, 這是, 第二, 個, 句子, 。]
done. Time elapsed: 419 ms
```

I once saw [someone](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:O-n5_2O6x_AJ:stackoverflow.com.80bola.com/questions/28167258/stanford-nlp-filenotfoundexception-while-processing-chinese-text&hl=zh-TW&gl=tw&strip=0) get the following log (CoreNLP 3.5.0) ; however oddly I do not have this log:

```
Adding annotator ssplit edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations:ssplit.boundaryTokenRegex=[.]|[!?]+|[。]|[！？]+
```

---

What's the problem ? Is there workaround? If unresolvable I can split it myself but I do not know how to integrate my splits into the CoreNLP pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I pull off a work around.

define the ssplit annotator myself.

For convenient I hardcoding the parameter here, though the right way should parse the props.

```
class MyWordsToSentencesAnnotator extends WordsToSentencesAnnotator(
  true,
  "[.]|[!?]+|[。]|[！？]+",
  null,
  null,
  "never") {
  def this(name: String, props: Properties) { this() }
}
```

and designate the class at property file.

```
customAnnotatorClass.myssplit = ...
```

---

Apparently ,I guess the default CoreNLP Pipeline setting or code has bug?

Comment: If I want to split a paragraph into sentences, can I just not use Stanford NLP Core and write a method that splits the text on  "[.]|[!?]+|[。]|[！？]+", ?

Comment: Of course, you can. I use coreNLP just because I want their pipeline framework.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem until I replaced the Chinese punctuation with its Unicode formats and set property as follows:

```
props.setProperty("ssplit.boundaryTokenRegex", "[.\u3002]|[!?\uFF01\uFF1F]+");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```